# Current flowing through serial pin

Tags: power

I have two microcontrollers linked together, with the intention of having them talk over serial, as shown below.
[image]

12V from the power supply is going into the board on the right. That 12V goes directly from that board to the board on the left (the screw terminals just break out the power coming in).

However, the 7805 (circled in green) gets very hot when that orange cable (a software serial line) is connected as it's shown here. I measure 50mA through it. Disconnecting the orange jumper returns the regulator the a normal temperature.

Is the board on the right powering the board on the left via the serial line? If so, how do I prevent this?

Edit: here is the schematic for the boards
[image]

Comment: Some schematic of the board would help.

Comment: @RonBeyer see edit

Comment: The order of your power terminals don't seem to match the schematic.

Comment: What's the name of your serial line in the schematic?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it's pin 19

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I use the hardware serial lines instead of SoftwareSerial. I will make this change, although I'm still interested as to why this happened.